# ASP MVC How to create custom FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

when I set the AuthCookie like this

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
```

the model.userName is actually the users email which is what uniquely identifies each user, then on my view when I use:

```
Welcome <strong> @User.Identity.Name</strong>!
```

it displays "Welcome user@mail.com!, however I would like to user the user.firstname.

So, my question is, is it possible to implement a custom User.Identity or a custom Forms.SetAuthCookie that will allow me to use something like this on my view:

```
Welcome <strong> @User.Identity.FirstName</strong>!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access some information provided by the [`MembershipUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) class. However, there is no property for first name or last name, which means you need to implement a custom membership user / provider. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).